# Blue ocean logging my step commands

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-blueocean

using a minimal jenkinsfile as an example

```
node("master") {
    stage("Test") {
        sh(
            label: "THIS SHOULD DISPLAY",
            script: "set -e; echo 'this should not be logged it is secret'"
        )
    }
}
```

For some reason the following occurs

[image: blue ocean logs]

I'm not sure what's going on here. Ideally I want the cmand not to be displayed and the label to take the place of the command.

Comment: The screenshot does not seem to match your code. It has set +x. Do you have a screenshot of the code you shared?

Comment: Can you also show a screenshot with the step expanded (click that arrow)

Answer (score 1):

1. If you run a script you have to specify where the output goes.
   sh(returnStdout: true, script: "echo 'this should not be logged it is secret'")
   returnStdout: true is standard, set it to false and nothing is shown
2. If you want to capture the output do.
   def msg = sh(returnStdout: false, script: "echo 'this should not be logged it is secret'")
3. label: "THIS SHOULD DISPLAY" puts a Label on the "sup"step to display on the Jenkins site. What you see is the intended result.

conclusion:

```
node("master") {
    stage("Test") {
      script {
        def msg = sh(
            returnStdout: false, 
            label: "THIS SHOULD DISPLAY",
            script: "set -e; echo 'this should not be logged it is secret'"
        )
        // do whatever you want with the output msg
      }
    }
}
```